# how to check for newline character in string input to an array in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, memory, input, mips

I am working on an assignment for MIPS assembly and this is my first time posting to stackoverflow and currently I am stuck on a part where I have to input string into an array and then terminate the input when I enter the newline character "\n". I am using memory mapped I/O and Polling.

```
.data
array: .word 0:10
.globl main
.text
main:
    la $s2,array
    li $t0, 0xffff0000 # Address of keyboard control register
    li $t1, 0 # Initialize wait_counter = 0
    li $s0,10
    li $s1,0
wait_keyboard:
    lw $t2, ($t0) # Read the keyboard control register
    andi $t2, $t2, 1 # Extract ready bit
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1 # wait_counter++ (counts iterations)
    beqz $t2, wait_keyboard # loop back while not ready
    lw $a0, 4($t0) # Get character from keyboard 
    addi $s1,$s1,1
    li $v0,11
    syscall
    sw $a0,($s2)
    addi  $s2,$s2,4
    
    beq $a0,'\n',end
    bne $s1,$s0,wait_keyboard
    
    
end:    
    

    #End Program
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

As you can see, I am checking for the newline character by using the beq $a0,'\n',end instruction which will end the loop after I enter the newline character .However this does not work as I enter the newline character for some reason. I would really appreciate it if you guys could tell me what I am doing wrong in this code.

I just need to know how exactly I can check for a newline character in input using memory mapped I/O and Polling.

Comment: It works for me.  Are you sure you have *loaded* and *connected* the "Keyboard and Display MMIO Simulator" tool?  You also have to click mouse to select the keyboard portion of the MMIO Simulator window to type your input characters into.

Comment: What simulator are you using (MARS, QtSpim)?